# Gatsby: Trying to get image path from front matter but getting this "TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Im building a blog with Gatsby and I'm trying to display a hero image on each post page with the image path that is defined in each posts front matter. But, I'm getting this error from my hero component:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined`

Here is my code:

**Post front matter**

```
---
path: /blog-post1
title: Blog Post 1
image: ../../images/blog-post-1.jpg
description: Blog post description
---
```

**Hero.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Img from "gatsby-image";

const Hero = props => (
  <section className="hero is-large">
    <Img
       fluid={props.frontmatter.image.childImageSharp.resize}
     />
     <div className="hero-body">
     </div>
  </section>
);

export default Hero
```

**Post.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';

import Layout from '../components/layout';
import Hero from '../components/hero';

const PostTemplate = ({ data }) => {
  const { markdownRemark } = data;
  const { frontmatter, html } = markdownRemark;
  return (
    <Layout>

      <Hero headerImage={frontmatter.image} />

      <section class="section">
        <div className="container is-medium">
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}} />
        </div>
      </section>

    </Layout>
  )
}

export default PostTemplate;

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($path: String!) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { path: { eq: $path } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        date
        path
        title
        description
        image {
          childImageSharp {
            resize(width: 1500, height: 1500) {
              src
            }
            fluid(maxWidth: 786) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Any ideas on what's happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out was the issue.

In my hero.js, I was calling the image using `{props.frontmatter.image.childImageSharp.resize}`

But in my post.js I was passing the data into the hero component like this `<Hero headerImage={frontmatter.image} />`

So, it was trying to find `frontmatter.image.image`, which doesn't exist. All I had to do was remove the `.image` like this `<Img fluid={props.headerImage.childImageSharp.resize} />`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have data in frontmatter variable all the time. If you look at how you are calling Hero Component, where you are passing data as headerImage.

```
 <Hero headerImage={frontmatter.image} />
```

If you look at Hero component you are reading it as **frontmatter**, You can do following changes and check.

You can add the condition to Img component to avoid the errors because of missing data.

```
{ 
   props.headerImage && props.headerImage.image && props.headerImage.image.childImageSharp
    <Img
       fluid={props.headerImage.image.childImageSharp.resize}
    />
}
```

Comment: So, I tried changing it to what you have and I got a different error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'childImageSharp' of undefined

Comment: This issue might be came becasue, initially you do not have the data. can you check what is the value of frontmatter in the render method of PostTemplate component. If at any point you do not have complete data, you will get this error.

Comment: Okay, I got it! Since i was passing frontmatter.image as headerImage, I didn't need to say headerImage.image because really that means frontmatter.image.image, which is wrong. So, I all i had to do was remove the .image. `<Img fluid={props.headerImage.childImageSharp.fluid} />`